# How to pass onClick event to parent component when using iteration in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, iteration, material-ui

I want to remove row of table after click event. I already created iteration and show delete button, but have no idea how to pass onClick event from parent to child component in my situation. 
I tried change `const row` to `component` and pass onClick like usually but this method destroys my table.

Parent component:

```
class Home extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { data: []};
}

handleDelete{
 alert('here I want to have code to remove row from table')
}

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <TableTasks data={this.state.data} header={[{ name: "No"}, { name: "Delete" }]} />
  </div>
);
}}
```

Child component:

```
const row = (props, i) =>
<TableRow key={`thr-${i}`}>
  <TableRowColumn>
    {props.nameTask}
  </TableRowColumn>
  <TableRowColumn className="DeleteButton">
    <IconButton>
      <DeleteIcon onClick={?????}/>
    </IconButton>
  </TableRowColumn>
</TableRow>;

export const TableTasks = ({ data, header }) => 
<Table>
 <TableHeader>
  <TableRow>
    {header.map((x, i) =>
      <TableHeaderColumn key={`thc-${i}`}>
        {x.name}
      </TableHeaderColumn>
    )}
  </TableRow>
 </TableHeader>
 <TableBody>
  {data.map((x, i) => row(x, i))}
 </TableBody>
</Table>;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps:

1- Pass a `handleDelete` function from parent to child `TableTasks` component:

```
<TableTasks handleDelete={this.handleDelete}  .... />
```

2- Define `handleDelete` in parent:

```
handleDelete(){....}
```

3- `handleDelete` will be available inside `TableTasks` component, destructure it similar to data:

```
export const TableTasks = ({ data, header, handleDelete }) => {...}
```

4- Now pass the `handleDelete` to `row` function:

```
{data.map((x, i) => row(x, i, handleDelete))}
```

5- Now `handleDelete` will be available:

```
const row = (props, i, handleDelete) => {
   console.log('handleDelete', handleDelete);
   return (
       ....
       <DeleteIcon onClick={handleDelete} />
       ....
   )
}
```